# Time Complexity Explanation with addition

Tags: time, complexity-theory

If i have something with O(logN) and add it to something with O(1)
Is the overall complexity still logN?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often big-O notation is an approximation.  For example, you might say `logN` when the actual complexity is `4logN + 7`.  This is still considered to be `logN` time, because the major factor is the behaviour as `N` changes.

If you had some algorithm that is `N^2 + logN`, then the most significant term is `N^2` and the `logN` quickly becomes unimportant as `N` increases...  In that case, you might simply say it is `O(N^2)` because it describes the characteristic time complexity of the algorithm.

So it depends on your needs.  If you simply need to describe the nature of the algorithm, then `logN` should suffice.  If you need to completely categorize every part of it or compare with similar but optimized algorithms, then add in all the terms.